# Why aren't my React Bootstrap Glyphicons showing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm using React Bootstrap's `Glyphicon` component but none of the glyphicons are showing up. Here is my code so far:

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Global from './components/Global';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Global />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Global.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Global extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <h2> Book Explorer!</h2>
              <FormGroup>
              <InputGroup>
                <FormControl
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search for a book"
                />
              <InputGroup.Addon>
                <Glyphicon glyph="search"></Glyphicon>
              </InputGroup.Addon>
            </InputGroup>
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Global;
```

Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the comment I am following along with a udemy course and it states nothing of including it in the index.html can you please elaborate on how to do so please? Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is because Bootstrap uses the font Gylphicon Halflings to display its glyphicons. Bootstrap's CSS must be explicitly included, as it imports the glyphicons, or else the glyphicons will not show up. You could add the `bootstrap.min.css` file to your `index.html` which imports it for you:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There was an issue [raised on GitHub](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2225#issuecomment-248672479) regarding this exact issue. It's not explicitly said that you need to include Bootstrap's CSS, and I ran into this issue before. You have to include the CSS file or else the glyphicons will not be imported and your components will display nothing.

Comment: To add to this a reason why this can resolve this issue is you may have a local copy of the bootstrap css which points to the cdn version of the fonts. You must download bootstrap properly and include the fonts folder in your code to make it work locally.

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap dropped Glyphicon support in v4
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components

Comment: Why did they abandon everything nice.

Comment: https://www.creative-tim.com/blog/web-design/bootstrap-glyphicons/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the react-bootstrap doesn't include the glyphicons component,
(I have checked the components there : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/)

So you would need to add glyphicons on top of the react-bootstrap package :

In the index.html file, add the following line :

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This should solve the issue without importing a second time the whole bootstrap css.